# Программно отключить монитор

Tags: winapi, c++

Доброго времени суток.

Возникла необходимость на некоторое время отключить программно монитор. Чем могу пользоваться: командной строкой (но вроде невозможно так), c++ (WinAPI наверно), ну на крайний случай c# с его .NET.

Искал, но находил советы вроде `SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM) 2);`. Это мне не подходит, так как если после запуска такого когда дернуть мышь или клавиатуру, то монитор просыпается. Мне же надо отключить жестко, чтобы включить обратно можно было только программно.

Comment: ищите по другому не выключайте монитор, а понижайте яркость. Правда не все мониторы позволяют это, но попробовать можно.

Но только я вижу одну потребность в подобном действии - вредительство.

Comment: Насчет вредительства я догадался, но задание дали в универе. А может как-то через ассемблерные команды попробовать? И еще: если уж пошла такая пьянка, то на крайняк можно и просто вырубить, то есть чтоб лечилось только перезагрузкой.

Comment: Ассемблерные команды это вряд ли, имхо старо и очень ненадежно.
Я думаю, вариант с винапи вполне уместен.

Comment: Вроде решился вопрос - в цикле крутить вот это:

    SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM) 2);

Пока сделал, что аргумент - это время и в течение этого времени цикл крутится. А нельзя ли запустить программу, а потом убить командой cmd? Ну чтобы я мог программно как выключить, так и включить?

Нет, оно в общем-то работает, но мои требования выше: я подключаюсь к компьютеру удаленно, при этом пользователя выбрасывает из системы (к окну выбора пользователя). Там монитор включен. :(

Comment: ах вот оно что. Просто поскупились на нормальную лицензию:)

Ставьте линукс, тут такой проблемы с глупым ограничением пользователей нет.

Comment: Я думаю, перед выключением монитора нужно отключить мышь и клавиатуру пользователя, чтоб он не вмешивался в процесс.

Comment: Смотри тут ===> https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1378379/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-1-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%b8%d0%b7-2

Answer (score 1):

`SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, 2);` //выключить
`SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, -1);`  //включить

Или:

```
HWND h = FindWindow(0, 0);
SendMessage(h, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, 2);
SendMessage(h, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Что если игнорировать сообщения посылаемые окну?

```
bool Flag=1;
 if (Flag=0) {
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

вот код который будет отключать монитор на прочь и включится только после того как нажмете пробел
[Как выключать только 1 монитор из 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1378379/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-1-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%b8%d0%b7-2/1379463#1379463)

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <vector>
    #include <lowlevelmonitorconfigurationapi.h>
    #include <windowsx.h>

    #pragma comment(lib, "Dxva2.lib")
    
    #define KEY_DOWN(key) ((::GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x80000) ? 1 : 0)
    #define KEY_UP(key)   ((::GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x80000) ? 0 : 1)
    
    const BYTE PowerMode = 0xD6;  // VCP Code defined in VESA Monitor Control Command Set (MCCS) standard
    const DWORD PowerOn = 0x01;
    const DWORD PowerOff = 0x04;
    
    // Monitor description struct
    struct MonitorDesc
    {
        HANDLE hdl;
        DWORD power;
    };
    
    // Monitor enumeration callback
    BOOL CALLBACK MonitorEnumProc(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData)
    {
        std::vector<MonitorDesc>* pMonitors = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<MonitorDesc>*>(dwData);
    
        DWORD nMonitorCount;
        if (GetNumberOfPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMonitor, &nMonitorCount))
        {
            PHYSICAL_MONITOR* pMons = new PHYSICAL_MONITOR[nMonitorCount];
    
            if (GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMonitor, nMonitorCount, pMons))
            {
                for (DWORD i = 0; i < nMonitorCount; i++)
                {
                    MonitorDesc desc;
                    desc.hdl = pMons[i].hPhysicalMonitor;
    
                    pMonitors->push_back(desc);
                }
            }
            delete[] pMons;
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
    
    // Switch monitor power
    void MonitorSwitch(MonitorDesc& monitor, DWORD mode)
    {
        if (monitor.power == mode)
            return;
    
        SetVCPFeature(monitor.hdl, PowerMode, mode);
        monitor.power = mode;
    }
    
    int main()
    {
    
        // Скрытие консоли 
    
        HWND hWnd;
        AllocConsole();
        hWnd = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL);
        ShowWindow(hWnd, 0);
    
        std::vector<MonitorDesc> monitors;
        EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, &MonitorEnumProc, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&monitors));
    
        // Init
        for (auto& monitor : monitors)
        {
            monitor.power = PowerOn;
        }
    
        // Here select the first one monitor as example
        MonitorDesc targetMonitor = monitors[0];
    
        while (1)
        {
            if (::GetAsyncKeyState('L') == -32767)
            {
                if (KEY_DOWN(VK_CONTROL) && KEY_DOWN(VK_MENU))
                    // turn off
                    if (targetMonitor.power == PowerOn)
                        MonitorSwitch(targetMonitor, PowerOff);
    
            }
            if (::GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE) == -32767)
            {
                if (KEY_DOWN(VK_SPACE))
                    // turn on
                    MonitorSwitch(targetMonitor, PowerOn);
            }
            if (::GetAsyncKeyState('E') == -32767)
            {
                if (KEY_DOWN(VK_CONTROL))
                    return 0;
            }
    
        }
    }
```