# Как выключать только 1 монитор из 2

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, монитор

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>



#define KEY_DOWN(key) ((::GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x80000) ? 1 : 0)


#define KEY_UP(key)   ((::GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x80000) ? 0 : 1)

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
        
        // Скрытие консоли 

            HWND hWnd;
            AllocConsole();
            hWnd = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL);
            ShowWindow(hWnd, 0);

        //Нажмите ctrl + alt + 'L' для блокировки / Нажмите ctrl + 'E' для завершения программы

            while (1)
                {
                    if (::GetAsyncKeyState('L') == -32767)
                    {
                        if (KEY_DOWN(VK_CONTROL) && KEY_DOWN(VK_MENU))
                            SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM)2); //Выключение монитора 
                    }
                    if (::GetAsyncKeyState('E') == -32767)
                    {
                        if (KEY_DOWN(VK_CONTROL))
                            return 0;
                    }
            }
            
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код рабочий, выключается 1 из 2 мониторов кому надо пользуйтесь.
Выключается монитор комбинацией Ctrl+Alt+L
Включается на Пробел (Space)
Если кто подскажет как сделать так что бы монитор включался от движения мыши
буду премного благодарен.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <vector>
    #include <lowlevelmonitorconfigurationapi.h>
    #include <windowsx.h>

    #pragma comment(lib, "Dxva2.lib")
    
    #define KEY_DOWN(key) ((::GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x80000) ? 1 : 0)
    #define KEY_UP(key)   ((::GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x80000) ? 0 : 1)
    
    const BYTE PowerMode = 0xD6;  // VCP Code defined in VESA Monitor Control Command Set (MCCS) standard
    const DWORD PowerOn = 0x01;
    const DWORD PowerOff = 0x04;
    
    // Monitor description struct
    struct MonitorDesc
    {
        HANDLE hdl;
        DWORD power;
    };
    
    // Monitor enumeration callback
    BOOL CALLBACK MonitorEnumProc(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData)
    {
        std::vector<MonitorDesc>* pMonitors = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<MonitorDesc>*>(dwData);
    
        DWORD nMonitorCount;
        if (GetNumberOfPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMonitor, &nMonitorCount))
        {
            PHYSICAL_MONITOR* pMons = new PHYSICAL_MONITOR[nMonitorCount];
    
            if (GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR(hMonitor, nMonitorCount, pMons))
            {
                for (DWORD i = 0; i < nMonitorCount; i++)
                {
                    MonitorDesc desc;
                    desc.hdl = pMons[i].hPhysicalMonitor;
    
                    pMonitors->push_back(desc);
                }
            }
            delete[] pMons;
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
    
    // Switch monitor power
    void MonitorSwitch(MonitorDesc& monitor, DWORD mode)
    {
        if (monitor.power == mode)
            return;
    
        SetVCPFeature(monitor.hdl, PowerMode, mode);
        monitor.power = mode;
    }
    
    int main()
    {
    
        // Скрытие консоли 
    
        HWND hWnd;
        AllocConsole();
        hWnd = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL);
        ShowWindow(hWnd, 0);
    
        std::vector<MonitorDesc> monitors;
        EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, &MonitorEnumProc, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&monitors));
    
        // Init
        for (auto& monitor : monitors)
        {
            monitor.power = PowerOn;
        }
    
        // Here select the first one monitor as example
        MonitorDesc targetMonitor = monitors[0];
    
        while (1)
        {
            if (::GetAsyncKeyState('L') == -32767)
            {
                if (KEY_DOWN(VK_CONTROL) && KEY_DOWN(VK_MENU))
                    // turn off
                    if (targetMonitor.power == PowerOn)
                        MonitorSwitch(targetMonitor, PowerOff);
    
            }
            if (::GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE) == -32767)
            {
                if (KEY_DOWN(VK_SPACE))
                    // turn on
                    MonitorSwitch(targetMonitor, PowerOn);
            }
            if (::GetAsyncKeyState('E') == -32767)
            {
                if (KEY_DOWN(VK_CONTROL))
                    return 0;
            }
    
        }
    }
```